# Java шаблон Observer и многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, инспекция-кода, observer

Мне необходимо создать приложение, которое будет получать данные по сети и передавать их другим классам для обработки. Я решила воспользоваться для этого шаблоном observer, но столкнулась с проблемой. Одновременно может поступить несколько соединений, поэтому для каждого я создаю новый экземпляр класса с принятием соединения и обработкой данных. Но как тогда правильно привязать наблюдателей к классу сервера. Чтобы использовать что-то в дополнительном потоке переменная должна быть статическая или финальная. Финальная не подходит, потому что на каждое соединение новый экземпляр сервера. А статическая меня смущает, я не совсем понимаю, как это работает.

Внизу приведен код, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это организовать, чтобы во время эксплуатации никакая фигня не вылезла.

Это главный класс

```
public class Main {
    static Server server = new Server();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int i = 0; // счётчик подключений
                    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(3013);

                    while(true)// слушаем порт
                    {
                        server = new Server(i, socket.accept());
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("init: " + e);                   
                }
            }
        }).start();

        ConcreteObserver observer = new ConcreteObserver(server);
    }
}
```

Это класс сервера

```
public class Server extends Thread implements Observable {
    Socket socket;
    int num;
    List<String> string = null;

    private static List<Observer> observers;

    public Server() {
        observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    }

    public Server(int num, Socket s) {
        this.num = num;
        this.socket = s;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // doing something
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void addObserver(Observer o) {
         if (o != null) { 
             observers.add(o);
         }
    }

    public void deleteObserver(Observer o) {
        if (o != null) {
            observers.remove(o);
        }
    }

    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            observer.update(listMettUnits);
        }
    }
}
```

И класс наблюдателя

```
public class ComputeAll implements Observer {
    private Server server =  null;

    public ComputeAll(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
        server.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(List<String> list) {
        // doing something
    }
}
```

Comment: А как и когда у вас регистрируются новые наблюдатели? Может ли новый наблюдатель зарегистрироваться, когда сервер уже запущен и принимает соединения? Тогда он должен зарегистрироваться у каждого существующего обработчика соединений? Или только для новых обработчиков, а существующие пусть продолжают работать как есть?

Comment: Новые наблюдатели регистрируются сразу после запуска приложения и все. Сразу создается и запускается поток с серверным сокетом, а потом добавляются наблюдатели. Теоретически может возникнуть ситуация, когда приложение запускается и соединение вклинивается между регистрацией двух наблюдателей, но вероятность не велика. Может, стоит регистрировать наблюдателей до запуска потока с сервером?

Comment: И еще один вопрос. Что происходит со ссылкой на сервер, когда один уже создан и принимает, и подключается второй. Приложение работает. Но что именно в этот момент происходит? Наблюдатели привязаны ведь к ссылке. Как notify от первого подключения достигает наблюдателей, если ссылка сервера привязана уже к новому экземпляру.

Comment: Наблюдатели-то в статическом списке, а он один на все экземпляры сервера.

Comment: Точно! Понимаю. Получается в целом решение жить будет. Есть еще что-то, что нужно обязательно учесть, чтобы проблем не было?

Answer (score 1):

По данному коду у меня есть несколько замечаний.

1. для observers не рекомендуется использовать `LinkedList`, лучше воспользоваться потокобезопасной реализацией, например `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`;
2. регистрировать наблюдателей предпочтительнее до запуска сервера.
3. Поля в классе `Server` и `ComputeAll` я бы сделал `final`
4. Запуск потока в его конструкторе не очень хорошая идея, и вообще, явное создание потоков не есть хорошо, воспользуйтесь, как вариант, `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`
5. И что касается не многопоточности, observers является статическим, что скорее всего не совсем верно.